# interrmitent connection to server

Tags: server

I am fairly new to Linux and am having some difficulty with connecting to the new Ubuntu server I have just installed.

Along with Ubuntu server 12.10, I have selected the default settings and have installed SSH during the initial install. PHP has been installed as well as apache. I have created a web application which works fine on another server so I believe that the application is not the issue.

Accessing the web interface from localhost works fine and seems to be consistent. Accessing from an external source via the servers IP is intermittent at best. Once connected, the application works just fine until the page gets refreshed or I save a change. At that point, the site connection becomes intermittent again. PING works without a hiccup. SSH also is experiencing the same intermittent issues.

Most of the time I get the following error:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

I am lost to find a solution for this and hope that someone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have been checking on our network and found that one of our new IP phones had been given the same IP address as this new server.

I changed the IP from DHCP to Static on the network and no longer have this problem.

Thank you for considering this question.
This issue has been resolved.